# Is it possible to use a subdomain login page to authenticate apps on multiple subdomains?

Tags: authentication, auth0

I'm looking to setup a login page on a subdomain for use with Auth0. Is it possible to have that login page serve auth for multiple other subdomains?

For example:

I want `login.xyz.com` to be the auth page for:

- `dev.xyz.com`
- `staging.xyz.com`
- `production.xyz.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to set up your login page to provide authentication for different subdomains (you could even set it up for different domains). One thing you have to remember is that a user will only have to log in once, and then will use their session among the different subdomains. This is because the user will actually log in to `login.xyz.com` and the other subdomains will only get a confirmation from your authorization server that the user is authenticated (most probably in the form of an ID token, if you're using OpenID Connect).

Comment: Interesting. Can `login.xyz.com` set a cookie for `staging.xyz.com`?

My vision is someone navigates to `staging.xyz.com` gets redirected to `login.xyz.com` (with a query param to mark that they're signing into staging), sign in, then get redirected back to `staging.xyz.com`. The same process for `production.xyz.com`.

Comment: No, it can't. The cookie will be set for `login.xyz.com`. In an OpenID Connect flow, `staging.xyz.com` will then get an ID token that will provide the user's identity. Then, `staging.xyz.com` will have to create its own cookie-based session based on the information from the ID token.